# How does logic gates know if electricity is flowing?

Tags: logic-gates

I'm studing software development and I'm reading about logic gates, but from all the material that I've read, it never explained how the logic gates know if there is eletricity flowing through a gate or not.

Here is were it gets me. Let's suppose you have a Not Gate and it had no eletricity flowing through the input, so now it goes from no electricity flowing to eletricity flowing through the output.

Comment: This depends on the exact construction of the gate (see http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/cmos-gate-circuitry/ ); but in CMOS it depends on voltage level and no electricity flows *through* in either the high or low state.

Comment: Imagine a NOT gate like a spring loaded relay. The contacts are normally closed so when there is no input signal (i.e. a "0"), the contacts are closed and allow power to flow from the output representing a "1" because that's it's normal state. When the input is set to "1" this energizes the "relay" and opens the contacts, because the contacts are now open, the output is now a "0".

Comment: Although it's not often shown on logical diagrams due to the clutter, gates are powered.  So besides the input and output of a NOT gate, there's also a power pin and ground.  The gate can use that power to read the input and modify the output.  Don't think the input is powering the output.

Answer (score 4):

This question is similar to asking "How does an apple know that a gravitational pull exists and that it shall draw to it?"

The basic answer is: The physics says so.

This is similar to your logic gate example. A logic "not" gate is just a symbolisation of reality. Scientists built a semiconductor device that had the "inversion of signal" behaviour and called it the "not gate". It's not the other way around.

Why there exists a material that can invert a signal? Well, technically, we don't know the "real" reason. We just know the laws of nature, deducted from experiments.

For example: the laws of physics says that a combination of these:
[image]

CMOS Two-input NOR Gate:
[Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vlsi_design/vlsi_design_combinational_mos_logic_circuits.htm)

Will act as a NOR gate which can be used to construct greater logic. How does a nor gate know about electricity? Well, it lies on the intricacies of P-N juntions and their combinations. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction)

The brief explanation of P-N junctions can be summarized as: "the electron give/take probability of (chemically) different materials."

So basically, you engineer a bunch of P-N structures and they act somehting like what mathematicians call a logical NOR.

By the way, I belive, NOR was a universal gate. So, you can create other logic gates from NOR. (That includes the NOT gate)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking for the basic idea of how logic gates work, not details of semiconductors or the philosophical basis of "knowing".

For simplicity, consider a 1970s microprocessor like the 6502 or Z-80. It is built from NMOS transistors. For our purposes, a NMOS transistor can be considered a switch that closes when it gets a 1 input. To build an inverter (left), an NMOS transistor is connected between the output and ground, with a resistor connected to +5V, as shown on the right.

[image]

If you put a 1 in, the transistor closes and grounds the output giving you 0 output. If you put a 0 in, the transistor is open and the resistor pulls the output high. Thus, you get an inverter.

If you put two transistors in series, you need both inputs high to get a 0 output (i.e. NAND). If you put two transistors in parallel, either input high gives a 0 output (i.e. NOR). So you can build more complex gates using the same principles.

Modern chips are based on CMOS, which Maximus's answer covers, so I won't get into that.

Answer (score -2):

All electronic devices work based on electricity flowing - I might now start to explain basics of Ohm, Kirchhoff, semiconductor devices...  But to be honest, you'd be better off with a textbook on electronics.

So: logic gates work based on electricity. It's the same as asking "how does a lever know mechanical force is exerted on it"; it doesn't "know", its action is a physical result of energy being transferred.